# how to improve efficiency of lesk algorithm in word sense disambiguation

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

Hi everyone currently I'm doing a project on word sense disambiguation and I have came across python implementation of lesk algorithm pywsd https://github.com/alvations/pywsd

How can get maximum correctness of sense using the above code

I have heard pos tagging helps to improve efficiency can anyone tell me how to add pos tagging to above lesk code and are there any methods where I can get maximum correctness of a particular sense

Comment: It all depends on the data that you're evaluating on. But usually, the `disambiguate()` function from `pywsd` gives you a decent baseline as shown in the "usage" example on the github page.

Comment: Sir can you tell me is there any implementation code  for enhanced lesk algorithm

Comment: Using `pywsd.disambiguate()` would have automagically POS tag your sentence in the process.